# a question on congruences

Tags: number-theory, finite-groups

I would like to prove that the following 2 are equivalent:

1. $\gcd(a,n)=1$ and $\exists x: x^m\equiv a \pmod n$
2. $a^{\frac{\phi(n)}{d}}\equiv 1 \pmod n$ where $d=\gcd(m,\phi(n))$

$\phi(n)$ is Euler 's function.

I've proved $1\rightarrow 2$.

Any ideas on $2\rightarrow 1$?

Comment: May I ask why did you use finite-groups tag here? Did you mean any certain approach or view?? Thanks.

Comment: Both elements $x,a$ belong to the finite order group of Units of $Z_n$ since they are invertible. That is $a,x\in \mathbb{Z^*}_n $ . I've tried to prove $2 \rightarrow 1$ using the fact that since $\mathbb{Z}_n^{*}$ is abelian of finite order it is isomorphic to the direct product of cyclic groups of finite order but had no luck.

Comment: Any idea is welcome, it doesn't have to be based on group theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not true that $(2)$ implies $(1)$. For example, let $n=8$, $m=2$, and $a=5$.

Here $\gcd(m,\varphi(n))=\gcd(2,4)=2$ and $5^2\equiv 1\pmod{8}$.

But $5$ is not  a square modulo $8$: any odd square is congruent to $1$ modulo $8$.

**Remark:** There are many other counterexamples.

Suppose that $n$ has a primitive root. It is not hard to show that in that case, $(2)$ implies $(1)$.

Comment: I was straggling 2 days for a proof… you’re so right.  
Indeed it is easy to prove it when n has a primitive root. Thank you so much.